# CSV parsing and conversion

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I'm looking to parse a csv file that is organized as follows:

```
<data1>,<data2>
asdf,<data3>
asdf,<data4>
asdf,<data5>
<data6>,<data7>
asdf,<data8>

<data1>,<data2>
asdf,<data3>
asdf,<data4>
asdf,<data5>
<data6>,<data7>
asdf,<data8>

<data1>,<data2>
asdf,<data3>
asdf,<data4>
asdf,<data5>
<data6>,<data7>
asdf,<data8>

etc.
```

I'm trying to output a .csv that looks as such:

```
<data1>,<data2>,<data3>,<data4>,<data6>,<data7>,<data8>
<data1>,<data2>,<data3>,<data4>,<data6>,<data7>,<data8>
etc.
```

Can someone help me out with this?

EDIT: figured it out, if anyone's interested..

```
import csv

with open('C:\Temp\eqtest.csv', 'rb') as inf, open('C:\Temp\output.csv', 'wb') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    i = -1
    line = []
    for row in reader:
        print(line)
        print(i)
        print(row)
        while row == ['','']:
            row = next(reader)
        i += 1
        if i == 0 or i == 4:
            line.append(row[0])
            line.append(row[1])
        elif i == 2 or i == 3:
            line.append(row[1])
        elif i == 5:
            line.append(row[1])
            i = -1
            writer.writerow(line)
            line = []
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to code this yourself? If so, please show your code and what your error is.

Comment: Presumably there are not really empty rows in-between?

Comment: @MartijnPieters there are empty rows

Comment: @andrejr: how many? An arbitrary number?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes. The program should output a new line whenever there is a line break in the input (shouldn't matter how many empty lines there are in between)...

Comment: @andrejr: but there are a fixed number of datapoints you are extracting, and they always follow the same pattern?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `csv.reader()` as an iterable, and get additional rows with [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) or [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as inf, open('output.csv', 'wb') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    for row in reader:
        while not row:
            # skip empty rows
            continue

        result = row
        for extra_row in islice(reader, 3):
            result.append(extra_row[1])
        result.extend(next(reader))
        result.append(next(reader)[1])

        writer.writerow(result)
```

This takes one row from the reader, and uses all columns as the start of the output row. It then pulls in an additional 3 rows from the same CSV to take the second column, adding it to the output row. With `next()` an extra two rows are read, adding the whole row and 1 column to the output.

Any empty rows before each block of 6 rows are skipped.

Then the output is read, and the next iteration of the `for` loop can begin, by which time 6 actual rows have been read and the loop picks up on row 7 from the input file; if this is empty, the reader is advanced until a non-empty row is found.

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import sys
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> sample = '''\
... <data1>,<data2>
... asdf,<data3>
... asdf,<data4>
... asdf,<data5>
... <data6>,<data7>
... asdf,<data8>
... 
... <data1>,<data2>
... asdf,<data3>
... asdf,<data4>
... asdf,<data5>
... <data6>,<data7>
... asdf,<data8>
... 
... <data1>,<data2>
... asdf,<data3>
... asdf,<data4>
... asdf,<data5>
... <data6>,<data7>
... asdf,<data8>
... '''.splitlines()
>>> reader = csv.reader(sample)
>>> writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
>>> for row in reader:
...     while not row:
...         # skip empty rows
...         continue
...     result = row
...     for extra_row in islice(reader, 3):
...         result.append(extra_row[1])
...     result.extend(next(reader))
...     result.append(next(reader)[1])
...     writer.writerow(result)
... 
<data1>,<data2>,<data3>,<data4>,<data5>,<data6>,<data7>,<data8>
<data1>,<data2>,<data3>,<data4>,<data5>,<data6>,<data7>,<data8>
<data1>,<data2>,<data3>,<data4>,<data5>,<data6>,<data7>,<data8>
```